# How do I manually dispatch actions to a store created with configureStore?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a project where half of it was made with classes, and the other half is being made with hooks and Redux.
For this, I have created a store with `configureStore()` from Redux Toolkit and provided it using the `Provider` component. In a very minimal way, the store is set up as follows:

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        user: {}
    },
    reducers: {
        validate: (state, action) => state.user = action.payload
    }
})

const store configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userSlice.reducer
    }
})
```

There are two components - a new one, functional, which uses the `useSelector()` hook, and an older one, which is class based, but needs to use this sasme store to dispatch an action.
To do this, I import the store and fire

```js
store.dispatch({type: 'user/validate', payload: newUser});
```

from the class component.
I receive no errors, yet nothing happens at all.

I tracked my input from DevTools' Redux plugin, and I can see the state does not change, so I assume my manual call to `dispatch` is somehow wrong.

What I expect to happen is for the state to update, which would trigger a re-render of the component that uses `useSelector`

Comment: Did the action get dispatched, you saw it in the redux-dev-tool? And you're just not seeing state update? Are you importing and dispatching from the same `store` object you created from `configureStore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following way is a safe way to dispatch actions without misspelling the type string.

1. Extract the action from reducer

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        user: {}
    },
    reducers: {
        validate: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload
          }
    }
})

// <------------------
// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { validate } = userSlice.actions


export const store =  configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userSlice.reducer
    }
})
```

2. Dispatch the action as so

```
store.dispatch(validate(newUser))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as the OP is using redux-toolkit.

Comment: Thank you, very elegant and working solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

I'm going to say the issue is that you are trying to both mutate your state object in the reducer function ***and*** return it.

See [Mutating and Returning State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#mutating-and-returning-state)

> In any given case reducer, **Immer expects that you will either *mutate*
> the existing state, *or* construct a new state value yourself and return
> it, but *not* both in the same function!**

## Solution

Just mutate the state, don't return it.

```
reducers: {
  validate: (state, action) => {
    state.user = action.payload;
  },
}
```

If you want your class-based component to subscribe to your redux store then you can still use the [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) Higher Order Component from `react-redux`.

Example:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { validate } from '../path/to/userSlice';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  ...

    // In a function you can simply dispatch the validate action
    // as it was wrapped in a call to dispatch already and injected
    // as a prop.
    this.props.validate(somePayloadValue);

  ...

}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  validate
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```